# What's the best order to remind users to complete their account information after registration

Tags: mobile-application, email, required-fields, push-notification, nudges

i'm designing a registration flow for an ecommerce app. Among the information needed, some information isn't needed immediately to complete registion. After filling in the minimum required fields, the user will be reminded later on to fill in the rest.

My question is, whats the best way to remind users to fill in the required information later. Would it be better to remind by

- Email
- Push notification
- On app launch

One concern is if users ignore one reminder, should the same channel be used to remind them again. Or are some users more likely to ignore certain channels than others? What would be a good flow to remind users who miss or ignore the 1st reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have EXACTLY the same user case with one of our clients.

In our particular case, since the client doesn't have a user registration flow in the same site (they use a third party vendor), we created an automation with a WP plugin that sends information to a **Google Sheet**. Then we pull the field from the sheet and send it to **Mailchimp** using **Zapier**. This is added to a list of *pending* users (they must send a photo). Once the user sends the photo, we delete it from the spreadsheet (manually) and the Mailchimp list is automatically updated. It's a very simple approach and the client is comfortable with it.

Keep in mind that you could do everything I mentioned completely automated with Zapier, but this particular project requires that manual intervention.

If you can get the user into your system, I think the less cumbersome way is the third option, *"on app launch"*. Pushes are easily dismissed and the user must approve them. Many users reject push messages on desktop by default, though it's not as common on mobile devices. Therefore, it also depends on your target device.

On the other hand, a [**Toast Notification**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/) when launching an app (web or mobile) briefly interrupts the flow, is easy to dismiss, yet informative, and lets the user know that the system is expecting something from them. The downside is that the user must first be identified as a user (logged in or with cookies).

## In short

- **if it's a true mobile app** (not a responsive website), choose either option 2 or 3 (or a combination of both).
- **If it's a responsive website**, then a combination of 1 and 3 is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Besides considering which channel to use, we also need to take consideration of what state of mind the user is in when you're showing the reminder, frequency of it being shown, and whats in it for the user if they complete the additional fields. A good ux copywriting would help as well. If the reminder shown doesn't align with the user's goal, most probably it will be put aside or ignored, not matter which channel you're using. But in general, "on app launch" might works best out of the 3 options, since user is focused on this particular app when the message is shown.